# Link a whole DIV

Tags: html, css

I want to LINK the "item-attributes" DIV. I can edit the HTML and CSS if needed, but I don't know how to make it work.

```css
.item-attributes {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.item-attributes__item {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.item-attributes__link i {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-attributes">
  <div class="item-attributes__item">
    <a href="#" class="item-attributes__link">
      <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just put everything that you want to link into the `a` element.

Comment: So… You want the whole `div` to be a clickable link? Just `<a href="…"><div>…</div></a>`.

Comment: it doesn't work, @helb.

Comment: @Alex you should update your code to show that you've done this and it will be easier to see the issue.

Comment: It definitely does work, you quite literally wrap the `<a href="...Your Link Here..."> <div>All your div content here</div></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way would be just to make the `.item-attributes__item` to be your link.

```css
.item-attributes {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.item-attributes__link {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #dfd;

}

.item-attributes__link i {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-attributes">
    <a href="#" class="item-attributes__link">
      <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right">Item</i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: this technically works, but removing my div from the structure messes up the rest of my page HTML. can I do it without removing divs from the structure?

Comment: The structure looks exactly the same as the one that you posted above. Your `<i>` element was offset in your original code based on the positioning, not sure if that's what you were intending or not.

Comment: You removed "item-attributes__item" from the code. I need that DIV to remain there. Can I make that whole DIV a link and still keep it a DIV?

Comment: @Alex I did remove `item-attributes__item`, but it was replaced with `item-attributes__link`. They both have the exact same CSS style. If you need the style for other places on your page, just add the `item-attributes__item` CSS code back in.